# Image Moves When Zoomed In

Tags: html, css

Hi guys im new to html and i'm working on a website project for my class. My problem is whenever I zoom in my image moves left or right. How can I make it stay. Thanks!

Heres My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ghost - Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel" rel="stylesheet"> 

</head>
<!-- Ghost Logo -->
<center><img src="images/gh_logo.png" alt="GH Logo" style="width:138px;height:198px;"></center>
<!-- End Ghost Logo -->
<img src="images/band_photo2.png" class="band-img" alt="image"/>

<div id="container">
```

CSS

```
body {

    background-image: url(../images/topback_gh2.png);  
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 0;
}

.band-img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 439px;




}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you are having is because of the pixel width of your browsers window is resizing when you are zooming in.

You have a large left margin on the image itself.

The solution to your problem is a CSS grid, of which there are plenty. 
(Bootstrap, simplegrid etc.)

A very lightweight and easy to use is the [Simplegrid](https://thisisdallas.github.io/Simple-Grid/)

```
<div class="grid">
 <div class="col-8-12">
 <!-- content for large column here -->
 </div>
 <div class="col-4-12">
 <!-- content for small column here -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Note: Your site's visitors might have different resolutions when viewing your site. I would suggest instead of you zooming in on your site, that you use the developer kit, google chrome have a great inspect kit for reviewing your site on different screen resolutions. A grid system also makes your site mobile friendly.